# Circular dependent methods in two different classes

Tags: objective-c

So I've been trying to organize my Objective-C code because as of now everything is in one huge file.
In a hypothetical situation:

- Class A has methods "alertCompleted" and "prepareAlert".
- Class B has a method "submitPost".

Let's say I'm in the A's method, "prepareAlert" from which I want to call B's method "submitPost". Then, from the "submitPost" method I need to call "alertCompleted" in A.

As you can see A calls methods in B and B calls methods in A. It's obviously ideal if I can have all the methods in the same class but I really need to organize my code (the methods above were just examples). How can I accomplish this? As far as I know categories only let the category class call the main class or vice verse but not both ways and importing each others headers gives me circular dependancy.

Comment: Why does `A.h` need to include `B.h`?

Comment: Won't A.h need to include B.h to use B's methods? or am I mistaken about that?

Comment: No, you should include it in the implementation file but not in the header.

Answer (score 3):

This is not really that big of a problem. You can use `@class <classname>` to create a forward.

ClassA.h

```
@class B;

@interface A : NSObject
- (void)needsB:(B *)b;
@end
```

ClassB.h

```
@class A;

@interface B : NSObject
- (void)needsA:(A *)a;
@end
```

It's in the .m file where you will need to import ClassA.h and ClassB.h

Answer (score 1):

Here's One Way, although it feels a bit excessive:

ClassA.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "ClassB.h"

@interface ClassA : NSObject

- (void) prepareAlert;

@end
```

ClassA.m

```
@implementation ClassA

- (void) prepareAlert {
    NSLog(@"Class A: Preparing Alert");

    ClassB * bClass = [ClassB new];
    [bClass submitPostWithTarget:self andCallback:@selector(handleCompletion)];
}

- (void) handleCompletion {
    NSLog(@"Class A: Handled Completion");
}

@end
```

ClassB.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ClassB : NSObject

- (void) submitPostWithTarget:(id)target andCallback:(SEL)callback;

@end
```

ClassB.m

```
#import "ClassB.h"

@implementation ClassB

- (void) submitPostWithTarget:(id)target andCallback:(SEL)callback {
    NSLog(@"Class B: Submitting Post");

    // Callback
    IMP imp = [target methodForSelector:callback];
    void (*func)(id, SEL) = (void *)imp;
    func(target, callback);
}

@end
```

Then When I want to call it:

```
#import "ClassA.h"
```

And Run Like So:

```
ClassA * aClass = [ClassA new];
[aClass prepareAlert];
```

Will Print:

```
2014-03-14 20:25:05.207 MyApp[52877:60b] Class A: Preparing Alert
2014-03-14 20:25:05.208 MyApp[52877:60b] Class B: Submitting Post
2014-03-14 20:25:05.209 MyApp[52877:60b] Class A: Handled Completion
```

This way, if you have a specific instantiation of ClassA that you want called from within ClassB, it will still work.